# Can not assign xp booster to everyone using quick.db in foreach syntax discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I'm trying to make global XP Booster system and now problem is that in foreach syntax it won't set it for all members, in fact, it won't set it for no one, actually, it can't get my params entered in command, in this case, it can't get my parameter 'kolicina' which means how much it would boost XP. This is the command:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const db = require("quick.db");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
            let allowed = false;
            if (message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) allowed = true;

            let vrsta = args[0];
            let kolicina = args[1];

            if (!allowed)
                return message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        title: `:star: Booster`,
                        description: "Nemaš permisiju za korištenje ove komande!",
                        color: 0x4CAAFF
                    }
                });

            if (!vrsta)
                return message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        title: `:star: Booster`,
                        description: "Nisi napisao/la vrstu boostera (1 - xp, 2 - kviz, 3 - drop)!",
                        color: 0x4CAAFF
                    }
                });
            if (!kolicina)
                return message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        title: `:star: Booster`,
                        description: "Nisi napisao/la količinu boostera!",
                        color: 0x4CAAFF
                    }
                });
            if (isNaN(vrsta) || isNaN(kolicina))
                return message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        title: `:star: Booster`,
                        description: "Svi argumenti moraju biti brojevi.",
                        color: 0x4CAAFF
                    }
                });
            if (vrsta === 2 && client.globalKviz === true)
                return message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        title: `:star: Booster`,
                        description: "Taj booster je vec ukljucen!",
                        color: 0x4CAAFF
                    }
                });
            if (vrsta === 3 && client.globalDrop === true)
                return message.channel.send({
                    embed: {
                        title: `:star: Booster`,
                        description: "Taj booster je vec ukljucen!",
                        color: 0x4CAAFF
                    }
                });

            if (vrsta === 1) {
                message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
                    db.set(`boosterxp_${message.guild.id}_${member.id}`, kolicina);
                });
                message.channel.send("uspesno odradjeno.");
            }
            exports.help = {
                name: "boosterall",
                description: "uključivanje globanih boostera",
                usage: "boosterall",
                category: "admin",
                listed: true
            };
```

So it can't set my parameter (kolicina) to boosterxp database, is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `boosterxp_${message.guild.id}_${member.id}` exist in **quick.db** already? Or you need to define it? As I can se from **quick.db**'s **npm** page,

```js
// Setting an object in the database:
db.set('userInfo', { difficulty: 'Easy' })
// -> { difficulty: 'Easy' }
 
// Pushing an element to an array (that doesn't exist yet) in an object:
db.push('userInfo.items', 'Sword')
// -> { difficulty: 'Easy', items: ['Sword'] }
```

In your case it would be

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
   db.set(`boosterxp_${message.guild.id}_${member.id}`, { kolicina: kolicina });
});
```

*ukoliko ti ovo ne radi, dodaj me na Discordu:* **deyyan#8737** *da pokusamo ovo riješiti na lakši način*

Comment: Odlično, ništa, srećno s daljnjim programiranjem bota :D